# How to find the width and height of the html content dynamically to pass to esri map infowindow.resize?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

There will be a html content stored in a variable with div id to pass into `infowindow`

```
map.infoWindow.resize(width,height);
map.infoWindow.setTitle("Callout");
map.infoWindow.setContent(calloutData );
map.infoWindow.show(event.screenPoint,map.getInfoWindowAnchor(event.screenPoint));
```

How can i pass the width and height to `infowindow.resize` dynamically? Is there any way the width and height of the html content can be calculated and pass without passing the value by us?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for dojo.position

```
var width = dojo.position("someNode").w;
var height = dojo.position("someNode").h;
```

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/position.html

Answer (score -1):

make a script which parses the html file and creates variables from the width and height tags

Comment: This requires those tags are set throughout and assumes the HTML is static.  If the content is in the DOM, you can use JavaScript to measure it, the jQuery API http://api.jquery.com/ is used for this sort of thing.  If not you may need to set the content first to make it measurable then resize.